# database is locked SQLITE3

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I am trying to add value to my DB, but I got error. Here is my code:

```
import sqlite3
curs = sqlite3.connect('Tadawul.db')
hello = "('hello')"
curs.execute("""INSERT INTO stock_price (close) VALUES """+ hello +""";""")
```

I got this error:

> sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked

How can I fix it?

I try this code nothing changes:

```
curs.execute("""INSERT INTO stock_price (close) VALUES (?)""",(hello, ))
```

Comment: Make sure that the db is not used by any other app.

Comment: You really should not do `"INSERT INTO stock_price (close) VALUES "+ hello +";"`, that opens the door to [SQL injections](https://xkcd.com/327/), always use parameters like in the second example you give.

Comment: I close the app that used the DB and no more errors, but the values didn't insert into the table. Why?

Comment: Did you add commit after the DML statement ?